# Consulta base de datos con función en PHP

Tags: php

Soy principiante en esto de programar en `php` y estoy intentando realizar una consulta a la base de datos con una función de una clase, pero al intentar ver el resultado, no me aparece nada en la pagina.

Mi clase es la siguiente:

```
class dbConnect
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "user";
    private $pass = "pass";
    private $db = "dbase";

    public function Connect()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if ($conn) {
            echo "Connected";
        }
    }

    public function consultaDB($tabla)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

La instancia que he creado es la siguiente:

```
$tb = new dbConnect();
echo $tb->consultaDB("CONTROL_VARIABLE");
```

He probado de hacer un `return` directamente del `mysqli_query` de la función `consultaDB`, pero sigue sin aparecer nada.

¿Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes publicar el código completo porfavor?

Comment: Este es todo el código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No te muestra los registros de la tabla porque no pides que se muestren.
Debes añadir modificar tu función `consultaDb` de esta forma :

```
function consultaDb($tabla) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']."\n"); 
            echo print_r($row);       
       }  
    }
```

Basicamente lo que haces aquí es guardar los valores de tu `query` en result, como ya habias hecho.

Te falta tan solo realizar el bucle `while` por tal de recorrer todos los registros almacenados en `$result`.

Para esto, se utiliza `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` que te devuelve los registros como un array associativo donde `clave = columna` y `valor = valorRegistro`, mostramos las columnas y valores tal y como se muestra dentro del bucle.

***NOTA :*** `nl2br` es utilizado para convertir `\n` en un salto de linea para que no se te muestren todos los datos en filas y no sea molesto. Si utilizaras `\n` sin más te seguirián saliendo los valores en linea.

***EJEMPLO DE SALIDA***
`( [id] => 52 [email] => alexc.igg7@gmail.com [password] => 1234 )` 
`( [id] => 53 [email] => alexc@gmail.com [password] => 1234 )`
`...`

***ASIGNACIÓN VARIABLES***
Por ejemplo, en caso de querer guardar en una variable el `email` del usuario con `id = 52` haríamos lo siguiente :

```
function consultaDb($tabla) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $result = $GLOBALS['mysql']->query($query);
        $email = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row[0]==52) {
                $email = $row[1];
            }
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']. PHP_EOL);
            echo print_r($row);  
        }  
    }
```

Donde tenemos en cuenta que `row[0]` pertenece a las ID's y `row[1]` a los email.

Si quisieras saber que indice `[X]` tienen las columnas de tus registros, si cambias `fecth_assoc` por `fetch_array` te devuelve también el índice de las columnas en el array.

*Otro ejemplo de asignación a variables*

```
function consultaDb($tabla,$id) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $result = $GLOBALS['mysql']->query($query);
        $email = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($row[0]==$id) {
                $email = $row[1];
            }
            echo nl2br ($row['column_name']. PHP_EOL);
            echo print_r($row);  
        }  
    }
```

Añadiendo el parámetro `$id` a tu función, guardamos en la variable `email` el valor encontrado si los id's coinciden.

Comment: Sería posible asignar solo el valor  `52`, siguiendo tu ejemplo, a una variable?

Comment: No hace falta recurrir a esto: `echo nl2br ($row['column_name']."\n");` cuando puedes optar por el salto de línea propio de PHP, así no tendrás problema en ningún contexto porque funciona en todas las plataformas: **`echo $row['column_name'].PHP_EOL;`** Para más detalles ver [*Constantes Predefinidas*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php) en el Manual de PHP. También decir que `fetch_assoc` no es el único método de lectura de resultados.

Comment: @A.Cedano Se de la existencia de `PHP.EOL` (de hecho tengo un pregunta donde tan solo utilizo `PHP.EOL`), si es verdad que es el salto de linea propio de PHP, es una buena aclaración. Y si, obviamente hay más métodos de lectura de resultados... Pero en este caso el idóneo es `fetch_assoc`... Le devuelve solo los valores que necesita. Por ejemplo, `fetch_array` y otros, creo yo que le devolvería información extra innecesaria.

Comment: @andyio Por supuesto, ahora te edito la respuesta con la asignación a variables

Comment: Usando lo que ha sugerido el sr Cedano, no funciona esta consulta. De todas formas, tendré en cuenta esta forma de hacerlo en futuras implementaciones.

Comment: @andyio Ya tienes la respuesta editada! Cualquier duda o aclaración deja un comentario! Un saludo ;D

Comment: Si usas `PHP_EOL` no tiene sentido usar `nl2br`, lo propongo precisamente como alternativa a esa función. Y mi aclaración sobre `fetch_assoc` era para señalar que no es el único método. Luego, según las necesidades se usará el método que mejor convenga. Yo suelo usar `fetch_assoc` por lo que dices en tu comentario: `fetch_array` te da los datos dos veces, con un índice numérico y otro asociativo. Mi comentario no era con la intención de que cambies de método. También con `fetch_assoc` puedes asignar cada valor a una variable si fuera necesario.

Comment: @A.Cedano No te preocupes, se que el comentario esta hecho con el fin de mejorar la respuesta! Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

$this->conn que utilizas en la función consultaDB no está definido como atributo de la clase dbConnect.

```
class dbConnect
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "user";
    private $pass = "pass";
    private $db = "dbase";
    private $conn;


    public function Connect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);

        if ($this->conn->connect_errno) {
          printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
          exit();
        }
    }

    public function consultaDB($tabla)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tabla}";
        echo "query -> " . $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        return $result;
    }
}

$tb = new dbConnect();
$tb->connect();
$resultado = $tb->consultaDB("CONTROL_VARIABLE");
print_r($resultado->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la consulta sigue sin aparecer, en la web, podría deberse a la instancia?

Comment: He impreso la query dentro de la función consultaDB y un print_r sobre el resultado de la consuta.

Comment: Igual me he explicado mal, la consulta aparece pero los datos de la base de datos no.

Comment: Y si imprimes con print_r, $resultado? comprueba si hay algún problema con la conexión https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Lo he probado y mismo resultado...

Comment: Puedes probar con PDO, lo he escrito en la respuesta, https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Comment: Entiendo que la consulta la ejecutas en el gestor y funciona perfectamente, y que está seleccionado el esquema correcto, con esquema.CONTROL_VARIABLE.

Comment: A tu respuesta solo le falta `$tb->Connect();` para ser correcta, quitando el PDO.  Añadiendo esto y el `fetch_assoc` que has indicado imprime el resultado correctamente.

Comment: Así como la he dejado ahora?

Comment: Por curiosidad, que versión de PHP estás usando? Es que tienes un método Connect y la clase se llama bdConnect... Me hace pensar que estás intentando usar ese método como constructor (algo así se hacía en versiones 4.0). Ahora sí ese método es constructor debería llamarse `__construct`